# 'background-size:cover' does not work in ipad

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad

Hello i am trying to create a parallax site. My code works well in every browser. But i am facing some problem at ipad. In ipad background-size: cover does not work.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
    var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the object
    $(window).scroll(function() {

      // Put together our final background position

      var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed'));
      var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';

      // Move the background
      $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });

    });
  });
});
```

```css
#section1 {
  background: url(images/hlfs-image.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat fixed; 
  min-height: 1000px ;
  height: 1000px ;
  margin: 0 auto ;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1920px ;
  position: relative ;
  background-size:cover ;

}
```

```html
 <section id="section1" data-type="background" data-speed="10" class="pages"> </section>
```

Can anyone give me a solution

Output [image: Output at browser]

[image: Output at ipad]

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
 #section1 {
      background: url(images/hlfs-image.jpg) 0% 0% no-repeat fixed; min-height: 1000px !important;
  height: 1000px !important;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1920px !important;
  position: relative !important;
  background-size:cover !important;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;

}
```

Mine is working with this..